# Create a new columns if at least two variables have the same response in a dataframe

Tags: r, if-statement, tidyr, reshape, mutate

I have tried a number of things but haven't been able to find anything that works just right.
I am trying to figure out how I can add a new column to my dataframe with a coded response if a single row has at least two identical variable responses.  My data has 42 columns so I have included a brief example but I need the output to include any response from all columns of the dataframe.

```
ID<- c(1,2,3,4,5)
CV<- c("Detected", "Not Detected", "Detected", "Not Detected", "Detected")
RV<- c("Not Detected", "Detected", "Not Detected", "Detected", "Not Detected")
BP<- c("Detected", "Detected", "Not Detected", "Detected", "Detected")
```

I would like the new column to be called "Coinfection" and if there are two observation responses per row that are "Detected" I would like the new column to indicate a "Coinfection" if there is only one observation responses that is "Detected" or all are "Not Detected" then I would like the column response to be "Negative".  So I would like it to look like this:

```
ID<- c(1,2,3,4,5)
CV<- c("Detected", "Not Detected", "Detected", "Not Detected", "Detected")
RV<- c("Not Detected", "Detected", "Not Detected", "Detected", "Not Detected")
BP<- c("Detected", "Detected", "Not Detected", "Detected", "Detected")

Coinfection<- c("Coinfection", "Coinfection", "Negative", "Coinfection", "Coinfection")

df<- data.frame(ID, CV, RV, BP, Coinfection)
    
ID          CV                RV               BP              Coinfection
1           Detected          Not Detected     Detected        Coinfection
2           Not Detected      Detected         Detected        Coinfection
3           Detected          Not Detected     Not Detected    Negative
4           Not Detected      Detected         Detected        Coinfection
5           Detected          Not Detected     Detected        Coinfection
```

Answer (score 3):

```r
df$Coinfection <- ifelse(rowSums(df == "Detected", na.rm = TRUE) >= 2, "Coinfection", "Negative"))
```

Comment: It seems that their may be some issue in my original data because all the responses in the Coinfection column are NA.  Any idea why that might happen?

Comment: Use `na.rm = TRUE`. It might be that you have NAs somewhere in your dataframe